# How to ensure API data is called and added with .then

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect

I am getting data in `useEffect` and looping through it to add additional data.

I want to do some calculations on it after all data being added to `results`, I make the calculations inside  `if (response.data.next)` but after that inside `then` when I try to access data it prints old data.

How can I make make sure all data added then be able to use it in `then`?

```
const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    async function handleAPIRequest(url) {
      return await axios
        .get(url)
        .then(async (response) => {
          await setResults((results) => [...results, ...response.data.results]);
          if (response.data.next) {
            await handleAPIRequest(response.data.next);
          }
          return results;
        })
        .then(async () => {
          // this is where I want to use results
          console.log("resultss: ", results);
        });
    }

    handleAPIRequest(url)

  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to keep consistency between async/await or chaining promises. your approach can cause multiple `setResults`, not sure if that's what you desire. Below, I offer a solution that might suit your needs:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function handleAPIRequest(url, currentResults = []) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url)
      const nextResults = [...currentResults, ...response.data.results];
      if (response.data.next) {
        return await handleAPIRequest(response.data.next, nextResults);
      }
      return nextResults;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  try {
    const finalResults = await handleAPIRequest(url);
    setResults(results => [...results, ...finalResults]);      
  } catch (error) {
    // here you can handle error response
    console.log(error);
  }
}, []);

// to do something after results state is updated use another use effect to accomplish that
useEffect(() => {
// do something on updated results state
}, [JSON.stringify(results)]);
```

Comment: because `results` is an array. if you pass an array or object as dependency, react it won't look its content, but it will compare their reference values. so you can have multiple `useEffect` triggers even the content is the same. using `JSON.stringify` is an approach to ensure to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code in the following way:

```
const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const handleAPIRequest = async url => {
    const lastResult = await axios.get(url);
    setResults([...results, ...lastResult.data.results]);
    const toLogResults =  [...results, ...lastResult.data.results];
    if(response.data.next) {
      await handleAPIRequest(response.data.next);
    } else {
      console.log("The final results are", toLogResults);
    }
  }
  handleAPIRequest(url)
}, []);
```

The main problem is that `results` in lines following `setResults()` are not updated immediately, so the value is the old one.

The `toLogResults` is used just to display the actual result, it is not needed.

Comment: @tarekhassan check the answer now and let me know. I noticed another problem later.

Comment: Updated again, please check the result now.